# How to access a specific row in MySQL using Java

Tags: java, mysql, server

When I write a name as a user, I need to access the surname for this name which is already in database. For example:

```
Enter a name: beste

beste's surname is: ozcaglar
```

When I execute my code I can't see any surname as output.

In my database, I have `name`, `surname` and `no` (Auto-Incremented) columns.

```
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.*;

public class ConnectionMySQL {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a name: ");
        String isim = scan.next();

        try {
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/student","root","");
            //System.out.println("Connection success");
            String query= "SELECT surname FROM student_table WHERE name='isim'";
            Statement stm =conn.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs= stm.executeQuery(query);

            while (rs.next()) {
                System.out.println("Name: " + rs.getString("name")+ " Surname: "+rs.getString("surname"));
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error means that the table doesn't have a column that is called "isim".

Maybe you meant to write:

```
SELECT surname FROM student_table WHERE name='isim'
```

?

EDIT (following the comments):

```
query = "SELECT surname FROM student_table WHERE name='" + isim + "'"
```

However this should not be used in a real-world application for security reasons (it allows SQL injection attacks).

In actual production code you should either escape input strings, or use parameterized queries...

Comment: Oh, yes thank you I didn't realise it. But when I wrote it like WHERE name='isim', I coulnd't reach see any result.

Comment: Are you sure you have a row that fits this criteria in the DB?

Comment: Yes. In the DB, I have "beste" as name and "ozcaglar" as surname.

Comment: but what's `isim`then if its not the name you are searching??? Your query should be `WHERE name='beste'`

Comment: Oh I see.. you want to add the content of a variable called "isim". Maybe like this - " ... WHERE name='" + isim + "'"

Comment: Yes, exactly I want to add the content of isim variable. I used your code but now I have an exception as "com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'beste' in 'where clause'" :(

Comment: We're getting there :) Can you paste the entire updated line where the query is defined?

Comment: @ThomasG I need to get "beste" as an user input.

Comment: yes we got it,  @obe  gave you the solution 3 comments earlier, but he should adapt it's answer

Comment: @obe I updated my question. I don't know what is the syntax problem. I think query is true.

Comment: You are missing the single quotes. I also updated my answer, please look at the new version...

Comment: Oh, thank you.. I learnt that where should I put the quotes now :D thank you so much buddy!! @obe

Answer (score 1):

You can follow this:

```
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.*;
public class test4 {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a name: ");
    String isim = scan.next();
    try {
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/test", "root", "");
            System.out.println("Connection success");
            String query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE surname='" + isim + "'";
            Statement stm = conn.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = stm.executeQuery(query);
            while (rs.next()) {
                String fName = rs.getString(1);
                String sName = rs.getString(2);
                System.out.println("Name: " + fName + " Surname: " + sName);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("Error");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: yes, it works but query should be like this : String query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE name='" + isim + "'"...Also, thank you for your answer too !

Comment: I think it's correct according to the table I created. Sorry I created my table with different name. Thanks